# CSS Background Repeat

Tags: css, background-repeat

Lets say I have an image with the width and height of 1700 x 1129px.  What is the best way to be able to repeat this image so that you cannot tell that it has been repeated.  I have tried using `repeat-y` but it looks like its another graphic.

[image]

Comment: How about `background-size: 100% 100%`? It will make the background cover the element completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to do with css. Your image does not allow repeating. To repeat an image without bad effects your image has to have same start and end in the direction you want it to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

There's a quite simple trick: end your image sides in a static color (like black or dark brown in your example), center your background image and color fill your background

`body { background: black url(image.png) no-repeat center top; }`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a *seamless* image, that means that the upper and lower edges as well as the left and right edges of the image match their opposite edge perfectly, so no angles and color transitions being visible. The css approach using `background-repeat` is totally fine.

That's often used in CG, mostly in the 3D world.
There's plenty of tutorials around on making an image seamless, found one [here](http://graphicssoft.about.com/library/weekly/aa080499p2.htm).

Comment: The word is "seamless". As in a "seam", a join in cloth or leather where two things have been stitched together.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry about that...fixing it

Answer (score 0):

Use [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size) property.

If you have a background which you think can be disguised by repeating horizontally then do the following.

```
background-size: 50% 100%; background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

if you think the background can be disguised by repeating vertically then do the following:

```
background-size: 100% 50%; background-repeat: repeat-y;
```